# No css for Gutenberg audio-block in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, audio, mediaelement.js, wordpress-gutenberg

Is there a way to style the gutenberg audio-blocks with css? The regular Wordpress Widgets and the Shortcode [audio] use mediaelement.js so it is no problem to style these Elements, but the output of the gutenberg audio-block is just a plain html audio-tag. Best would be to use mediaelement.js for those aswell - I wonder why this is not a default.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick&dirty Solution for this problem. I added the following code right before the end of the header-tag to apply mediaelement.js to gutenberg-audio-blocks

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".wp-block-audio audio").addClass("mejs__player");
        });
</script>
<script src="/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-includes/js/mediaelement/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
```

The links to the mediaelement js and css only have to be added, if you do not already have a sidebar with an audio-widget visible on all pages of your website - in this case the mediaelement js and css are added automatically.

As I mentioned: this is just a Hack and no real long-term solution. I guess there is a cleaner way to solve the problem with some code in the functions.php
Proposals are welcome.